# How can I combine two byte values into one?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, xor

So this is a breakup on what I was doing, the value that I am using is 0x0123456789abcdef with picking index, a = 0, b = 1; a = ef, b = cd.

first I separated the indexes for which ever ones they picked and this worked perfectly.

Value A: 0x00000000000000ef.

Value B: 0x00000000000000cd.

Then I moved them to the place where the other one previously was index at which this also worked perfectly.

Value A: 0x000000000000ef00.

Value B: 0x00000000000000cd.

Then I combined the A and B values together using the | operator which also worked perfectly and stored them into a long int P

Value P: 0x000000000000efcd.

Then I decided to finally combine this with the x value of 0x0123456789abcdef

And the way I decided to do this is at first I used the vor operator.

so I did p = x ^ p;

And with the math I did

0x0123456789abcdef

0x000000000000efcd.

---

0x0123456789ab0000

It should become that but for some reason it results in

0x0123456789ab2222 and I don't understand how the 2222 appear there. Is there any way I can go about to get the output I desire of 0x0123456789abefcd

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with your post, i.e. your code for attempting to manipulate this value

Answer (score 1):

Hex `0xE` has bits `1110`; hex `0xC` has bits `1100`; therefore `0xC ^ 0xE` is `0010` or `0x2`.  Hence when you xor those two hex digits, you end up with a result of `2`.

Similarly, `0xF` has bits `1111`; hex `0xD` has bits `1101`; therefore `0xF ^ 0xD` is `0010` or `0x2`.

Hence, the result you see is exactly what you should expect.